# How to form a dynamic json array in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a set of values in my db. After reading that, my output will be
like below.

```
FetchValues = 
  [{
   "Key": "123"
    "Value":"aa"
     "Type":"A"},
    {},
    {}
   ]
```

I need to form a dynamic json array like below after fetching the values from DB.

```
 {
  "A":{
   "123" : "aa"
  },
 {
  "B": {
    "124" : "bb"
  }
 }


 var Json = {}
for(k=0;k<fetchValues.length;k++)
{
  Json.push({ fetchValues[k].Type        
  : {
    fetchValues[k].Key : fetchValues[k].Value
    }
   })
```

But it gives error. Kindly help on this.

Comment: Please include the error you are receiving.

Comment: It is syntax error while trying to form a json and push in to an array

Comment: By JSON, do you mean object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may leverage [destructuring syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) within [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const src = [{Key:"123",Value:"aa",Type:"A"},{Key:"124",Value:"bb",Type:"B"}],
     
     result = src.map(({Key, Value, Type}) => ({[Type]:{[Key]:Value}}))
     
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Or (if your actual intention was to output an object, rather than array):

```js
const src = [{Key:"123",Value:"aa",Type:"A"},{Key:"124",Value:"bb",Type:"B"}],
     
     result = src.reduce((acc, {Key, Value, Type}) => 
      (acc[Type] = {[Key]:Value}, acc), {})
     
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Answer (score 1):

[@Yevgen Gorbunkov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11299053/yevgen-gorbunkov)'s answer is way better, but here's an approach using `forEach`:

```js
const src = [{Key:"123",Value:"aa",Type:"A"},{Key:"124",Value:"bb",Type:"B"}];

let res = {};
src.forEach(element => res[element.Type] = { [element.Key]: element.Value });
```